# Angular Live Server start

Tags: node.js, angular

When i run npm start everything is successfully compiled, in the end write me :

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

But if i go to open localhost:4200 i don't have any data:

**This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response.**

But if i open http://127.0.0.1:4200/ the i see the website.

How i can change the setting for run the web site on http://localhost:4200 and not in 127.....?

Comment: localhost is same as 127.0.0.1

Comment: and so why my website didn't run on it? but before was ok?

Answer (score 2):

Check your host (if you are in windows) file you will find it on

> C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

then add the following line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: i already have    # 127.0.0.1       localhost on the file

Comment: remove the **#** symbol

Comment: i I understand the problem, when i open the http://localhost this go to https so doesn't work, i stop this automatic redirect with https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome